# Having an issue with spacing in bash script

Tags: bash, if-statement, scripting, find, quoting

I am trying to perform an if/else with the find command as the conditional. I am getting errors with because of the spacing in a directory. I have done a lot of searching on here and google and I'm unable to resolve this issue. Thank you for your help in advance.

**My Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
dir="/to/Two Words/test/"
file="test.txt"

if [ `find $dir -name $file` ];
then
    echo "File $file is in $dir"
else
    echo "$file is not in $dir"
fi
```

**The results:**

```
find: ‘/to/Two’: No such file or directory
find: ‘Words/test/’: No such file or directory
test.txt is not in /to/Two Words/test/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to double-quote `$dir` to avoid [word
splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/wordsplitting) but anyway it's
not going to work:

```
$ ./f.sh
./f.sh: line 5: [: space: binary operator expected
```

You want:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
dir="/to/Two Words/test/"
file="test.txt"

if [[ -n "$(find "$dir" -name "$file")" ]]
then
    echo "File $file is in $dir"
else
    echo "$file is not in $dir"
fi
```

Comment: I have to wait to mark your answer but this worked. Thank you! What should I look into to learn more about this?

Comment: You could start from an official [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual)

Comment: @spry [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like this. I also recommend [Greg's BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ).

Answer (score 1):

`if` does not require `[` for command executions, but `find` returns 0 even if no files were located. Try using a pipeline with a `grep`.

```
if find "$dir" -name "$file" | grep .
```

The grep will return false if it fails a match.

Comment: Certainly quote your vars to protect the spaces in directory and file names.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the whitespace, `$dir` expands to two args; add quotes to prevent that, `find "$dir"` ...